# Why won't my code run on Visual Studio when I try it on a database instead of a simple list ?

Tags: python, database, for-loop, pyodbc

This code used to run perfectly on a simple list, but since I've been trying to run it on a database, I get a StopIteration error in my double for loop. 
EDIT : Now my probleme is I just don't get any type of error, the command line is the empty when I run it.

Here's my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
import re 
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

[x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('Microsoft Access Driver')]

# Connection to accdb

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\\Users\\alice\\Desktop\\lexique3.accdb;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# Put all words into a list 

crsr.execute("select unites_lexicales from Mot where cat_grammat='Verbe' or 'Nom' or 'Adjectif' or 'Adverbe'")
resultat = crsr.fetchall()
words = [row[0] for row in resultat]
#print(words)

# Remove unwanted characters and put radicals into a list

radicals = [] 
motifp = "^(an|re|dé|dés)" 
motifs = "(ist|man|er|an|able|asyon)$" 

for word in words : 
    word = re.sub(motifp, '', word) 
    word = re.sub(motifs, '', word) 
    radicals.append(word) 
#print(radicals) 

# Match radicals and put words into new lists

ratio = 0.6
n = len(radicals)
result = []
used_js = []

for i in range(n) :
    if i in used_js:
        continue
    matches = [words[i]]
    js = (x for x in range(n) if x != i and x not in used_js)
    for j in js : # Previous error : StopIteration
        if SequenceMatcher(None, radicals[i], radicals[j]).ratio() >= ratio : 
            matches.append(words[j])
            used_js.append(j)
    result.append(matches)
print(result)
```

The expected result is the following (which I previously had with a simple list) :

```
['flore', 'fleur', 'fleuriste'], ['remaniement', 'remanier', 'manier', 'maniable'], ['désaimer', 'aimer', 'aimant'], ['mêler', 'emmêler', 'désemmêler']
```

Having tried each part of the code separately, everything works fine besides the double for loop. 
Any clue about why I can't run it and how I can fix this would be really helpful.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE If that works using print_stack(), nothing appears when I run it.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Visual Studio tells me there's absolutely no error, but the code still won't run.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the problem ? "Standard library module invoked user code during import; breakpoints disabled for invoked code" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have `StopIteration` because:

```
(x for x in range(n) if x != i and x not in used_js)
```

is an iterator which yield no items. In other words, the list `[x for x in range(n) if x != i and x not in used_js]` is empty.

You ought to use a classic `for` loop:

```
for j in range(n):
    if j != i and j not in used_js:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, radicals[i], radicals[j]).ratio() >= ratio : 
            matches.append(words[j])
            used_js.append(j)
```

You can also replace your generator expression by a list, like this:

```
js = [x for x in range(n) if x != i and x not in used_js]
for j in js:
    if SequenceMatcher(None, radicals[i], radicals[j]).ratio() >= ratio : 
        matches.append(words[j])
        used_js.append(j)
```

Comment: Iterating over an iterator that yields no items is supposed to just perform 0 iterations, though. The for loop is supposed to handle the StopIteration.

Comment: Using a for-loop over an exhausted iterator will not throw a `StopIteration`

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately it still doesn't work for me... but this time I don't even get an error message, it's just a dark screen, nothing displays.